# How can I connect to a Firebird database JDBC driver using Python?

Tags: python, firebird

I want to connect Firebird database. And I am using DBeaver for Firebird database. However, I need to connect Firebird using Python. I have found connecting with ODBC driver but I am using JDBC driver. That is the description https://docs.devart.com/odbc/firebird/python.htm
How can I connect fdb file?

Python: Python  3.10.2 version
VS Code

Comment: You cannot (or should not) use JDBC nor ODBC to connect from Python. You need to use the Python [firebird-driver](https://pypi.org/project/firebird-driver/) (uses fbclient.dll/libfbclient.so), or [pyFirebirdsql](https://pypi.org/project/firebirdsql/) (pure Python). The FDB driver is deprecated and replaced by firebird-driver.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem like this:

```
import fdb

con = fdb.connect(database='fdb file path', user='SYSDBA', password=password,charset='UTF8' )

cur = con.cursor()
```

A basic example for Firebird connection. The other issue here "import fdb". I couldn't install it right place. And then I have installed here:

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages

then fixed the problem.